# prometheus: does rate() work in sliding window?

Tags: prometheus

Does the `rate()` work in sliding window or thumbing window? For example, the scrape interval is 10s, and it keeps scraping for 10 minutes, when I query `rate(foobar[1m])`, what does it means?

For each second, it calculates the average within the range back from that second?

Or, each minute calculates the average, i.e. for this case, it calculates 10 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute `rate(foobar[1m])` it uses the last minute of data and returns a result for a single timestamp. PromQL has no knowledge of your scrape interval or how long you've been scraping for.

There's also the `query_range` HTTP API which will preform multiple independent PromQL evaluations `step` seconds apart. You want the time ranges covered by these evaluations to overlap, so you probably want a `step` of no more than 30s here.

Comment: You mean the range always backed from the query time, right? So if the client queries `rate(foobar[1m])` per second, then the results are in sliding window way, right?

Comment: WIth Grafana, how to graph QPS per minute from prometheus? That is, split the time series into non-overlapping minute units, and calculates the QPS in each unit.

Comment: If you're looking for an exact answer to that, you need a log-based monitoring system as a metrics-based system fundamentally cannot provide that.

Comment: No, my requirement is simple, I need to graph qps calculated per minute. Could you answer how to do this with grafana and prometheus just like I described above?

Comment: That's impossible, Prometheus is a metrics based system and thus doesn't have the information that could calculate that. It can do things which are good enough, but it can't do exactly what you asked for.

Comment: No, I think prometheus can do that. If I query prometheus once a minute with `rate(foobar[1m])`, then I could get my expected result, right?

Comment: You'll get a number similar to that, but not exactly. It'll include some data from the previous minute and won't cover all data points.

Comment: In grafana, I should set `Min step` and `Resolution` to make it work, right? http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/prometheus/